# C++ : Class & callbacks issue

Tags: c++

Here is my code & requirements:

I have 2 classes A & B, they don't have any inheritance. I used one method of class A to call one method of Class B. Then the class B's method should callback one of the class A's method to execute a callback.

Part of code:

classA.h:

```
#include "classB.h"

class classA
{
  public:
  classA();
  classB *pClassB;
  void callClassB();
  void callBack();
};
```

classA.cpp:

```
#include "classA.h"
classA::classA()
{
  pClassB = new classB();
}

void classA::callBack()
{
  return;
}

void classA::callClassB()
{
  pClassB->callFunction();
}
```

classB.h:

```
class classB
{
  public:
  classB();
  void callFunction();
}
```

classB.cpp:

```
#include "classB.h"
classB::classB()
{
}

void classB::callFunction()
{
   // I should call classA's callback here!
}
```

The problem is, I can't include classA.h in classB.h because it will cause some compile issue elsewhere(I can't solve that). I can't make classB as classA's subclass(if I can, I just have to do `classA::callBack()` instead). So is there a solution to this situation?

UPDATE：that's what I've modified:

```
class classB
{
  public:
  classB(classA& pCallBack);
  void callFunction();
  void (classA::*m_callback)(void);
};

classA::classA()
{
  pClassB = new classB(*this);
}

classB::classB(classA& pCallBack)
{
  m_callback = pCallBack;
}
```

I tried to save the pointer, but also failed. It says "assigning from incompatible type"... what's wrong with it??

Comment: C does not have classes, member function, and operator new. The C tag is not justified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, reciprocally including both headers in each other is a circular dependency, which the compiler can't resolve. There are different ways to solve this, three of which I describe below.

#### Using forward declarations

The most straightforward way to break the circular dependency is to use *forward declarations*. A forward declaration only tells the compiler that a given name denotes a class. That is enough if you only use pointers/references to that type, because in these cases the compiler doesn't need the full definition of that type. So you can change *classA.h* like this:

```
class classB;

class classA
{
  public:
  classA();
  classB *pClassB;
  void callClassB();
  void callBack();
};
```

This way the header is not dependent on *classB.h* anymore. Of course, you need now to `#include` that header in *classA.cpp*:

```
#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"
...
```

#### Introducing an interface

Another way is to introduce a super interface (or in C++, an abstract superclass) to `classA`, and let `classB` see only that:

callback.h:

```
class callback
{
  public:
  virtual void callBack() = 0;
};
```

classA.h:

```
#include "callback.h"

class classB;

class classA : public callback
{
  public:
  classA();
  classB *pClassB;
  void callClassB();
  void callBack();
};
```

classB.h:

```
#include "callback.h"

class classB
{
  callback& m_a;
public:
  classB(callback& a);
  void callFunction();
};
```

classB.cpp:

```
#include "classB.h"

classB::classB(callback& a) : m_a(a) {}

classB::callFunction()
{
  m_a.callBack();
}
```

As you see, this way `classB` does not depend on `classA` in any way. This in fact allows you to later replace `classA` with any other implementation of `callback`, without touching `classB`'s definition.

#### Introducing a function pointer

Yet another possibility would be to define / use a function pointer type matching that of `classA::callBack()`, and pass only the pointer to the callback function to `classB`, rather than the whole `classA` object. Although, this only works seamlessly with `static` methods - for nonstatic functions you still need a `classA` object for the call.

### Update

You are mixing two approaches (passing an object of `classA` or passing only a function pointer) in your modified code. Better stick with one at a time. The first approach is simpler, this is how it would look like:

```
class classA;

class classB
{
  classA& m_a;
public:
  classB(classA& a);
  void callFunction();
};

classB::classB(classA& a) : m_a(a) {}

classB::callFunction()
{
  m_a.callBack();
}
```

The function pointer approach would be more complex for nonstatic member functions, because you needed *both* the function pointer and an object on which to invoke it. An alternative take on it is shown in @Tadeusz's answer.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply, but unfortunately in my case I can't pass anything to classB. Your first solution should work, but I wonder if there is a better solution :)

Comment: @Syhou Assuming the callback is synchronous (and maybe if it isn't), providing an intermediary interface is the 'right' answer.

Comment: So, you basically do a forward declaration (as I pointed out), to get around the fact you need to put references or pointers to e.g. classB in the header of classA and vice versa. There is no need fo a super-class per se to avoid the circular reference.

Comment: As an aside it is better to use *forward declarations* as much as possible - it speeds up compilation especially if you change one of the headers.

Comment: @Ed Heal: Couldn't agree more. Sadly I never get any upvotes when I answer questions, maybe my style of writing is bad, i dunno...

Comment: @Syhou, if you can't pass anything to `classB`, how it is supposed to know where to call back to? It needs to have either a function pointer or an object reference/pointer in order to do a callback. This can be passed as a (constructor / method) parameter, or made available through a global variable (which is ugly and not recommended).

Comment: Can you give me a brief example about how to pass the object reference to classB as a constructor parameter? I tried something and failed, you can see my edited codes in my question.

Comment: OMG finally it works!! These are all excellent examples & implementations for newbie who wants to establish connections between classes & have callbacks! THX for you guys' hard work!!

Comment: @S.C.Madsen THX for your codes but seems your expression is still not clear enough for a dull n00b like me :) Just keep going, LOL

Answer (score 3):

If you need just a callback, there is no need for class B to know anything about class A. Just pass a callback. I'll give a boost (pre C++11) solution:

classB.h:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class classB
{
    void callFunction(boost::function<void()> callback);
}
```

classB.cpp

```
void classB::callFunction(boost::function<void()> callback)
{
    callback();
}
```

classA.cpp:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void classA::callBack()
{
  return;
}

void classA::callClassB()
{
  pClassB->callFunction(boost::bind(&classA::callBack, this));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use forward declarations, e.g:

classA.h:

```
class classB; // forward declaration
class classA
{
  public:
  classA();
  classB *pClassB;
  void callClassB();
  void callBack();
};
```

classB.h:

```
class classA; // forward declaration
class classB
{
  public:
  classB();
  void callFunction(classA& a);
  // could store pointer to classA instance here instead
}
```

This works as long as you are only using references or pointers to classB in classA.h and vice versa.

classA.cpp:

```
#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"
classA::classA()
{
  pClassB = new classB(); // could pass 'this' to classB here instead
}

void classA::callBack()
{
  return;
}

void classA::callClassB()
{
  pClassB->callFunction(*this);
}
```

classB.cpp:

```
#include "classB.h"
#include "classA.h"
classB::classB()
{
}

void classB::callFunction(classA& a)
{
   a.callback();
}
```