# C++ member callback with forward declaration

Tags: c++, callback, c++11

I'm having the following class setup (here only with relevant content):

```cpp
// Message.h
class Message { };
typedef std::shared_ptr<Message> MessagePtr;
```

```cpp
// Task.h
#include "Message.h"

/*
 * On include of Communication.h compilation fails.
 */

class Task {
public:
    send(const MessagePtr &msg) {
        // Call to Communication::send
    }

    MessagePtr recv() {
        // Call to Communication::recv
    }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Task> TaskPtr;
```

```cpp
// Base.h
#include "Task.h"

class Base {
    std::map<TaskPtr, std::vector<TaskPtr>> taskMap;
};
```

```cpp
// Runtime.h
#include "Base.h"

class Runtime : public Base { };
```

```cpp
// Communication.h
#include "Base.h"

class Message; // Forward declaration

class Communication : public Base {
public:
    void send(const TaskPtr &caller, const MessagePtr &msg);
    MessagePtr recv(const TaskPtr &caller);
};
```

My goal is to provide kind of an independent communication layer within `Communication` to let tasks communicate with each other. The receiver list is defined within `taskMap` (kind of publish-subscribe where the sender does not know the receivers).

For this purpose my idea is to use a callback function (e.g. with `std::bind` or similar) from `Task` to `Communication`. However, I'm not able to implement this, since whenever I include the `Communication` Header within `Task` compilation fails, which is, due to circular includes.

So I'm not sure about how to forward declare `send` / `recv` from `Communication` to use them within `Task`. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10244177/172695) question, which is similar and also provides good answers, **but** I'd like to avoid to place a pointer to `Communication` within `Task`. The best possible solution seems to me to introduce kind of forward declaration for the members of `Communication`, but I'm afraid that I don't know how to accomplish this.

I've also thought about the class setup, whether it fits the purpose, but didn't come up with a better solution yet.

Comment: Can you split the code up into separate pieces so it's clear which things are declared in which headers? And maybe a comment showing where you would like to be able to insert a callback function?

Comment: Done, also added the current includes and a note on what include compilation fails.

Comment: Nice. Now where do `Task::send()` and `recv()` get an instance of `Communication` from? And are you really defining those functions inline in the class definition, or in a separate `Task.cpp` file? (No need to edit the code if you can give simple answers to these.)

Comment: looks like you don't understand jow forward declaration works. Did you have any `.cpp` file in project? Implement `send`/`recv` in `cpp` file which includes `Communication.h` and `Task.h` and you will have no cyclic dependencies.

Comment: @Oktalist Functions are currently defined inline, but I'm going to change this. Initially I wanted to work header only (but this doesn't seems to work). The best (in terms of "wishes") would be if `Task` nothing knows about the instance of `Communication`, that's why I wanted to use `std::bind`, possibly `Runtime` can have the instance of `Communication`. Alternatively I could make those members static.

Comment: @Rost no `.cpp`'s yet, I initially wanted this to be header only, but this won't work then with forward declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the declaration outside of the class. It doesn't prevent the library to be header-only, as you could `inline` those functions. You could arrange the functions like:

```
// Task.h
#include "Message.h"

class Task {
public:
    inline void send(const MessagePtr &msg);
    inline MessagePtr recv();
//  ^^^^^^
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Task> TaskPtr;
```

```
// Communication.h
#include "Base.h"
#include "Task.h"

class Communication : public Base {
public:
    void send(const TaskPtr &caller, const MessagePtr &msg);
    MessagePtr recv(const TaskPtr &caller);
};
```

```
// Task.impl.h
#include "Communication.h"

inline void Task::send(const MessagePtr &msg) {
    // call Communication::send
}

inline MessagePtr Task::recv() {
    // call Communication::recv
}
```

And include `Task.impl.h` to have the two task methods defined.

Comment: Oh! Never thought about defining another header and using `inline`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
// Task.h
#include "Message.h"

class Task {
public:
    typedef std::function<void(const MessagePtr&)> SendFunc;
    typedef std::function<MessagePtr()> RecvFunc;
private:
    SendFunc sendfunc;
    RecvFunc recvfunc;
public:
    void setSendFunc(SendFunc& f) { sendfunc = f; }
    void setRecvFunc(RecvFunc& f) { recvfunc = f; }

    send(const MessagePtr &msg) {
        if (sendfunc) { /* call sendfunc */ }
    }
    MessagePtr recv() {
        if (recvfunc) { /* call recvfunc */ }
    }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Task> TaskPtr;
```

```cpp
// Communication.h
#include "Base.h"

class Communication : public Base {
public:
    void send(const TaskPtr &caller, const MessagePtr &msg);
    MessagePtr recv(const TaskPtr &caller);
};
```

```cpp
// in a function somewhere
taskptr->setSendFunc(std::bind(Communication::send, communicationInstance, taskptr));
taskptr->setRecvFunc(std::bind(Communication::recv, communicationInstance, taskptr));
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution, I've accepted the other one, since it directly targets header only, but I've upvoted this one also.